# i cant find rinkeby even after turning on test net on metamask, who else is having this issue?

Tags: metamask, testnets

I can't find Rinkeby even after turning on the testnet on Metamask. Who else is having this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Its because Rinkeby is removed from default networks, it is mentioned in the following PRs.

It is encouraged to use Goreli or Sepolia testnets.

[Metamask extension deprecation](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/15295)

[Metamask mobile deprecation](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile/issues/4697)

Answer (score 0):

Rinkeby has been deprecated after the merge

Goerli & sepolia work fine

You can find them in the default testnet options